# Bash conditional statement results in bad substitution

Tags: bash, conditional-statements

I am learning how to use bash and I ran into a bad substitution error with the following code

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ ${1,,} = herbert ]; then
    echo "Oh, you're the boss here. Welcome!"
elif [ ${1,,} = help ]; then
    echo "Just enter your username, duh!"
else
    echo "I don't know who you are. But you're not the boss of me!"
fi
```

the line highlighted to be responsible for this is line 3: ${1,,}. How do I resolve this?

Comment: What substitution are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Edit your question and tell us what you expect that `${1,,}` is supposed to do. OR you can copy/paste all of your code into https://shellcheck.net and fix any errors flagged and see if that solves your problem. Good luck.

Comment: Which version of BASH?

Comment: Are you actually using Bash?

Comment: the line is fully legal, so it should work. Maybe you have a very ancient bash version, or some fake bash, not implementing all substitution options?

off topic: you should surround the variables with double quotes to avoid syntax errors when variable is empty.

Comment: The `${parameter,,}` expansion was introduced with version 4.0 of Bash. It won't work if your Bash version is older, or your shell isn't Bash. As an aside, you should quote the expansion: `"${1,,}"`

Comment: This very much looks like you're running too old of a release.

Comment: I am using version 3.2 let me try upgrading and run the code again

Comment: I linked to a question about how to compare strings in a case-insensitive way, because that's what the code you're trying/failing to run is for. As others have said, the reason it doesn't work is that bash 3.2 is too old to support this syntax; the duplicate has answers that describe this version constraint and have alternatives that aren't tied to it.

Comment: The issue was with the bash version. Upgrading it resolved my issue. Thanks